# Make forever watching be working even after closing the command promt

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I run my Nodejs project with

```
forever start app.js
```

the script continues to work after I close the command promt, as expected. But watching the file changes doesn't work

If I run the script with

```
forever -w app.js
```

the watching works, but if I close the command promt, the watching stops working and I don't see file changes in the browser (though it looks like the script still works?)

Is it possible to run the script continuously so that it would be working even after closing the command promt, but at the same time with watching the file changes?

ps. I use Windows binary version of Nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) package as the solution. After installing, it's enough to run

```
pm2 start app.js --watch
```